# asp.net access label from another class

Tags: asp.net

I have a label and a button and when I press the button the label changes.
Now in order to continue i need to be able to access the label from another class. I tried to change the definition to public static in the aspx.designer.cs file but when I do that the button that changed the label before stopped working - i get a null exception. I tried to init the label but i can't find the right place to do it. Making a static method in the class, that will change the label's text didn't work as well because i can't change a non static variable in a static method.
How can I access a label from another class without getting a null exception or effecting the button that worked?

Comment: You need to pass a reference to the page.

Comment: how can i do that? so far when i tried that i got errors but i guess i just didn't do it correctly

Comment: Are you in a user control in the page?

Answer (score 0):

From a UserControl or a WebControl, you can access the Page with `this.Page`:

```
//From the Control File:
this.Page.TheLabel.Text = "blah";
```

Just make sure the label is public or you have a getter, and that you're not in a HttpContext (Not in a static method).

FIY, making the label static in the page would means there would only be one instance on the label shared by all the instance of pages. I doubt thats what you wants.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can add a public property to the web control. Assign the label value to the public property and use it in any other place. It is better not to directly access label value from other files